# How to Iterate two loops using forEach concept

Tags: node.js, foreach

I have two arrays like below and implemented the iterations using old for loop approach. However, how can I get the same in forEach().

```
var questions =['your name', 'SkillSet', 'exp']
var answers =['King', 'Nodejs', '5']

for(let i = 0; i<questions.length; i++){
htmlobj += '<tr><th>'+questions[i]+'</th></tr>'
htmlobj += '<tr><th>'+answers[i]+'</th></tr>'
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want a new row for each item you add to `htmlobj`?  This HTML is going to create a single column with alternating values from the two arrays where each new value is in a new row.  That seems an unlikely presentation format.  Wouldn't you want question and answer in the same row?

Comment: yes new row for each question and answer, i am created the object with <tr>.

Answer (score 0):

```
let htmlobj = ""
questions.forEach((el, index) => {
  htmlobj += '<tr><th>'+el+'</th></tr>'
  htmlobj += '<tr><th>'+answers[index]+'</th></tr>'
})
```

Comment: thanks for the response @jfriend00. however, we are not using el any where in logic, Does it makes sense as good coding practice.

Comment: @jfriend00, okay. try like the edited version. el instead of questions[index]

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much consider a `.forEach()` loop to be obsolete these days because a `for` loop is so much more flexible.  With modern Javascript, you can use `for/of` and still get value and index:

```js
const questions =['your name', 'SkillSet', 'exp']
const answers =['King', 'Nodejs', '5']
let htmlobj = "";

for (const [index, question] of questions.entries()) {
    htmlobj += `<tr><th>${question}</th></tr><tr><th>${answers[index]}</th></tr>`;
}

console.log(htmlobj);
```

While the additional flow control advantages of a `for` loop aren't being used here, they are very useful in many other circumstances and the regular `for` loop doesn't incur the function overhead of calling a callback function for every iteration of the loop.

---

And, if you want one row for each question and answer, you would need to change the HTML like this:

```js
    const questions =['Your Name', 'SkillSet', 'Exp']
    const answers =['King', 'Nodejs', '5']
    let htmlobj = "";

    for (const [index, question] of questions.entries()) {
        htmlobj += `<tr><th>${question}</th><th>${answers[index]}</th></tr>`;
    }

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = htmlobj;
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
    text-align: left; 
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table id=result></table>
```

Comment: @kingslight - Added a version of the code that puts each question/answer in their own row and shows you the resulting table (if you run the snippet).